# Mysql strings only get saved up to about 277 char

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im using ruby on rails with a mysql db in the back. I realized, that the characters are limited up to about 277 per column entry...

How can I increase this?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: What's the data type for the column you want to increase the size of?  The CREATE TABLE statement would help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change_column :the_table_name, :the_column_name, :string, :limit => 1024 # where 1024 is your desired limit

Answer (score 0):

Changing the field type from text to mediumtext would allow you to enter more characters

**PK**